# Update KDE Plasma on kUbuntu 22.04

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu, plasma

Is there any way to upgrade KDE Plasma from 5.24 to 5.27 on kUbuntu 22.04 (without upgrading to kUbuntu 23)?

Comment: There is no Kubuntu 23; there is 23.04 (which is EOL) & Kubuntu 23.10; however have you looked at Kubuntu backports (https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports) as they offer a number of upgrades which you can take according to your risk level (*the highest version can have issues with non-KDE software due to required updated libraries/toolkit you need for KDE Plasma; thus your choice of what you apply or how far you upgrade*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you read https://kubuntu.org/news/plasma-5-27-lts-for-jammy-22-04-lts-available-via-ppa/

> We have had many requests to make Plasma 5.27 available in our
> backports PPA for Jammy Jellyfish 22.04. However, for technical
> reasons this would have broken upgrades to Kinetic 22.10 while that
> upgrade path existed. Now that Kinetic is end of life, it is possible
> to allow opt in backports of plasma 5.27 for 22.04.
>
> As with the previous backport of plasma 5.25, 5.27 is provided in the
> backports-extra PPA
>
> This PPA is intended to be used in combination with our standard
> backports PPA, but should also work standalone.
>
> As usual with our PPAs, there is the caveat that the PPA may receive
> additional updates and new releases of KDE Plasma, Gear (Apps) and
> Frameworks, plus other apps and required libraries. Users should
> always review proposed updates to decide whether they wish to receive
> them.
>
> While we feel these backports will be beneficial to enthusiastic
> adopters, users wanting to use a more tested Plasma release on the
> 22.04 base may find it advisable to stay with Plasma 5.24 as included in the original 22.04 (Jammy) release.
>
> To add the PPA and upgrade, do:
>
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports-extra && sudo apt
> full-upgrade -y
>
> We hope keen adopters enjoy using Plasma 5.27

ie. use Kubuntu *backports*

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports-extra && sudo apt full-upgrade -y
```

FYI:  I'll suggest you read all docs though; as that far forward requires the use of *backports-extra*, which has more risk involved than the other options available for Kubuntu 22.04 LTS and *backports*.

Also please ensure you note the warning "*This PPA is intended to be used in combination with our standard backports PPA, but should also work standalone.*"  ie. I'm recommending you add the standard as well (*assuming you've added backports*).

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the lengthy explanation and warning. Can you please share the standalone PPA as well?

Comment: It was provided in my initial comment; ie. you can add using `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports`... ie. what I quoted from in this answer is to get *newer* software (*albeit at higher risk*) using the **extra** backports option...  refer https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports

Comment: FYI:  I have ~no experience with this PPA, and am no expert in this area at all (*I'm on other teams*). My *opinion* is based on what I understand from *devs* talking in -devel rooms on IRC who are involved and in the Kubuntu team.   Testing of *backports-extra* alone was successful, however its still seen as less *risky* with the standard backports PPA (*that received much more testing*) as well.  We all use our systems differently, with different 3rd party packages, thus we can experience issues where the QA testers did not.

Comment: do you suggest to upgrade to 23.10 to get Plasma 5.27 because it will be safer?

Comment: That is a much more difficult question...   I'll answer that with what I would consider. I do consider 23.10 *safer* than 22.04 LTS with *backports* & *backports-extra*, esp. if using many non-KDE apps (esp. probably Qt5 apps most especially; I'm on the Lubuntu team thus *partially* why we're told of what Kubuntu are doing as we also use Qt5).. however the additional risk itself is rather small most probably *unless* you're unlucky & require a package impacted by an issue not considered by *devs*. 23.10 is rather close to what 24.04 will have, thus you'll go thru biggest change in the ...

Comment: 22.04 to 23.10 *bump*, and have a pretty smooth bump going from 23.10 to 24.04 in the future... HOWEVER there is less 3rd party software packaged for non-LTS releases, thus I'd check what software you actually need; and ensure it's packaged from 23.10 before you *jump*, as LTS releases (thus 22.04) do have considerable more 3rd party software packaged for them... thus I'd check 23.10 will do everything you require from it first. Yes I do consider 23.10 a *tad safer*, but I do trust the Kubuntu team & those who QA-tested the PPA, but was anything missed in the discussions?  We don't believe so.

Comment: I ended up upgrading using backports and backports-extra ppa on 22.04 and my system works pretty smooth. UI, GTK apps and third-party are working like before.